# Login to ubuntu 18.04 server as root

Tags: 18.04, server

I am in a weird situation and was wondering if anyone can help. I college professor and I have a server computer at my university and the system administrator who was in charge of the machine left the job while I was away during summer. He gave the root password of the machine to my department chair before leaving who in turn gave it to me. But I am not in the sudo list. How do I login to the server as root and add myself to the sudo list so that I can install and upgrade any required packages? Any help will be really really really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add yourself to `/etc/sudoers` file from your own account if you do not currently have privleges to edit it.

Since you have the `root` password you can use the following command:

```
su root
```

It will prompt your for a password where you should enter the root user's password to login as root. Now you are root user and you should be able to make any changes to the machine you like.

Remember to run
`exit`
when you are done to prevent yourself from doing any unintentional harm to the computer. This will log you out as root.

*EDIT:*
Clarification on `su` usage on Stormlord's comment. By default running `su` will log you in as `root` user. `su` can be used to login as any other user in your system if you provide the name of that user as argument to `su`

Comment: This I do after doing SSH using my user account right? Once I am logged in as user, and do su root and enter root password, I get su: Authentication failure.

Comment: `su root` is a redundant command. `su` by itself means *super user*. If you do have the correct root password, type `su --login` in a terminal and you will be asked for the root password. If this doesn't work, your password is probably incorrect or the ssh server does not allow you to log in as root at all.

Comment: even after su --login I get 'su: Authentication failure'. Does that mean there is no other way? Only option is reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: Have you looked at the existing users on the system? Did your administrator say it was the root password or just the admin password? You might have another account that is allowed to sudo (eg. `su - admin`, which in turn allows you to `sudo whoami`).